# How can I apply a code to a zip file while also changing the filetype in the output zip folder?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, zip

I have a code that I am trying to use on a zip file in python and I want the output to be another zip file, but with the files changed to .txt or .csv.
The code I have runs without error, but fails to change the file type and I am unable to determine if the contents are being changed.
I am able to change single .psa files taken from the zip one at a time, and the outcome is a .csv file with the desired modifications.

Breakdown:
I have a zip folder that consists of .psa files.
I have a code that can read an individual .psa file and output a .csv with the modifications.
I want to apply this code to the zip folder with all the .psa files instead of manually carrying out this process for individual files.
Currently the code that applies to the individual file requires me to name the output file within the code.
It would be helpful if the resulting file carried the same name as the input, just with the filetype designation changed to .csv.

Bonus: It would be even nicer if the output of the zip folder was just one .csv file which included the contents of all output files within the output zip folder. I think this would solve the naming issue. (So basically just one file output instead of many.)

Below is the code which works on individual files: This code takes a .psa file and converts it to a .csv while also changing the contents.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

`fname = '1 Area 2 - store 15 group.psa'
df = pd.read_csv(fname, usecols=[0,1,2], header=None, names=['type','upc', 'num'])
store = re.search(r'store\s+(\d+)', fname).group(1)
df = df[df['type'] == 'prod'].drop(columns=['type','upc']).assign(store=store)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False) `
```

Below is the code I'm applying to the zip file. The result is that a new zipfile is being created, but the files within it are the same .psa filetype.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import zipfile
import os
 
input_zip_path = r'test.zip'
output_zip_path = 'results.zip'
 
def process_file(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=[0,1,2], header=None, names=['type','upc','num'])
    store = re.search(r'store\s+(\d+)',file_path).group(1)
    df = df[df['type']=='prod'].drop(columns=['type','upc']).assign(store=store)
    df.to_csv("name.csv", index=False)
    return df
 
with zipfile.ZipFile(input_zip_path, 'r') as zin, zipfile.ZipFile(output_zip_path, 'w') as zout:
    for file_info in zin.infolist():
        with zin.open(file_info) as f, open(file_info.filename, 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(str(f.read()))
        modified_df = process_file(file_info.filename)
        modified_df.to_csv(file_info.filename, index=False)
        zout.write(file_info.filename)
        os.remove(file_info.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Change `zout.write(file_info.filename)` to `zout.write("name.csv")`

### Breakdown

Let's break down this part of your code:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(input_zip_path, 'r') as zin, zipfile.ZipFile(output_zip_path, 'w') as zout:
    for file_info in zin.infolist():
        with zin.open(file_info) as f, open(file_info.filename, 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(str(f.read()))
        modified_df = process_file(file_info.filename)
        modified_df.to_csv(file_info.filename, index=False)
        zout.write(file_info.filename)
        os.remove(file_info.filename)
```

So, for each file in the zip you are trying to:

1. Read out each file inside the zipfile
2. Write the contents to a new file outside of the zip
3. Process each outside file and transform them to a CSV
4. Write the files to a new zipfile
5. Remove the outside file

Where it goes wrong at least with your current code is between steps 3 and 4.

When you process the outside files, you do the following

```
df.to_csv("name.csv", index=False)
```

This stores the end result to a new file "name.csv".

However, what you are writing back to a zip is:

```
zout.write(file_info.filename)
```

Here, `file_info.filename` is NOT the file `name.csv` that you just created, it just the original outside file, and that's what you end up with.

So you might want to change that to:

```
zout.write("name.csv")
```

### Further improvements

I also think that the part where you write the files to outside is unnecessary, you might be able to just directly read the contents from the files inside the zip with pandas, something like this:

```
with zin.open(file_info) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[0,1,2], header=None, names=['type','upc', 'num'])
```